# Regular users can indirectly delete feed bot messages

Tags: bug, chat, feed

Once more, [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) has uncovered an exceptionally obscure chat bug. We noticed that, apparently, [a regular user managed to delete one of the feed messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/26376012/history) in our chatroom. I think that link only works for mods, so here is a screenshot:

[image]

It turns out that he didn't actually delete that message directly. Here is what happened:

- You need a normal message from a regular user (that is not too old for them to delete yet) and a message from one of the normal feed chat bots. The order of the posts doesn't matter (so you can wait until the feed is posted before the regular user has to post their message).
- Have a mod edit the feed message to reply to the regular user's message.
- Have the regular user delete their message.

This will delete the reply along with it, listing the regular user as the person who deleted it. That seems pretty odd (and I'm quite sad that my witty feed post edit was lost ;)).

We also tried this with normal messages, and thankfully it didn't work there (I think it would be quite horrible if anyone could delete other users' posts by deleting their own if they received a reply). So I'd definitely consider this a bug.

---

I suppose you could ask why anyone would edit a feed message to reply to another user in the first place, but at least in our chatroom that actually happens quite often, when an impatient user posts the same onebox as the bot a few minutes earlier. In that case, the mods usually delete or edit the bot post to remove the clutter from chat.

Comment: Okay but that seems like a tremendous edge case.