# "You have starred and pinned this message"—no I haven't

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-transcript

> [Once more, The Nineteenth Byte has uncovered an exceptionally obscure chat bug.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271690/180276)

When I click the dropdown arrow from the transcript next to [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26377157#26377157), I see:

[image: screenshot]

However, I've only starred it, and the message isn't pinned at all:

[image: screenshot 2]

I can reproduce this for any message that I've starred.

Comment: wasn't pinning and starring on the same endpoint without the knowledge what you did?

Comment: Interesting that it does happen only with the transcript.

Comment: I'm starting to get the impression that the only purpose of that room is to annoy blue blobs, and break chat.

Comment: @Zizouz212 pretty much