# Mobile allows triple-pinning

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, chat-pins

> [Once again, The Nineteenth byte has uncovered an strange and unusual obscure chat bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271764/286591)

Normally, if you attempt to pin a message that has already been pinned by another user, you get the following:

[image]

However, the mobile site allows room owners to pin messages that are already pinned. For example, if you look at the history on [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/35811125/history), you can see that it has been pinned by three different room owners. Martin originally pinned it, and then both Mego and I pinned it again from mobile.

[image]

Comment: That... Is... *Awesome!*

Comment: If it's pinned three times, does that mean it's been stapled and spindled?

Comment: So if anything needs to be stress tested just send it to TNB 

Actually don't send it to the TNB if it will bork things

Comment: @Shog so it's [tag:status-too-awesome-to-fix]?